# Trying to submit one <form> with method="POST" duplicates the route and doesn't save the information with an store function()

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

***Im trying to submit one form with method post to save one element in a`store function()` but when I click submit duplicates the route, for example looking like this:`entradas/1/ventaEntrada/200000/montoTotal/entradas/1/ventaEntrada/200000/montoTotal` and doesn't save the information, I dont know why this is happening***

- Below i will let the code of my route,my `form`,my `create function()` and my `store function()`
- Also show`404 Not Found` when I click submit

***Route***

```php
Route::resource('/entradas/{id_entrada}/ventaEntrada/{precio_entrada}/montoTotal', 'Venta_entradaController');
```

***`create function()`***

```php
public function create(Request $request,$id_entrada,$precio_entrada){
    $venta_entrada = DB::select(DB::raw(
                                        "SELECT monto_total,fecha,fk_cliente_natural,fk_cliente_juridico
                                         FROM venta_entrada "
                                         )
                                );
    return view('home.crearVenta_entrada')
                    ->with('venta_entrada',$venta_entrada)
                    ->with('id_entrada',$id_entrada)->with('precio_entrada',$precio_entrada);
}
```

***`store function()`***

```php
public function store(Request $request,$id_entrada,$precio_entrada)
    {
        $venta_entrada=new Venta_entrada();
        $venta_entrada->monto_total=$precio_entrada+$request->monto_total;
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $venta_entrada->fecha=$now->format('d-m-Y');
        $venta_entrada->fk_cliente_natural=1;
        $venta_entrada->save();
        return back();
    }
```

***Form with the method POST***

```html
<form action="entradas/{{$id_entrada}}/ventaEntrada/{{$precio_entrada}}/montoTotal" method="POST">
        @csrf        
       <input type="number" name="monto_total" placeholder="Monto total" class="form-control mb-2" required>       
       <button clas="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">ADD</button>
       <a href="/entradas/1/ventaEntrada/1/montoTotal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">BACK</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: did you tried action="{{ url('entradas/{id_entrada}/ventaEntrada/{precio_entrada}/montoTotal') }}"

Comment: also try to remove "/" from route. Route::resource('entradas/{id_entrada}/ventaEntrada/{precio_entrada}/montoTotal', 'Venta_entradaController');

Comment: Did `action="{{ url('entradas/{id_entrada}/ventaEntrada/{precio_entrada}/montoTotal') }}` and said syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: I remove the `/` but also didn't work

Comment: <form action="{{ url('entradas/'.$id_entrada.'/ventaEntrada/'.$precio_entrada.'/montoTotal') }}" method="POST">  try to pass the data with route url

Answer (score 3):

I have check your problem and you have use "Resource Route" right.

so for routing run following command in your terminal/command prompt

```
php artisan route:list
```

It will show all routes lists and find your action name

Then you'll add in form action name like

```
<form action="{{ route('name') }}" method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

Example:

```
<form action="{{ route('Venta_entrada.store') }}" method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

I hope it will help you :)